# Printing out XSLT transformed XML document in Java Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xslt, glassfish

I am trying to print out a transformed XML document using a Java Servlet (GlassFish Server). I am getting the xml from an external website, transforming it with XSLT, and then trying to print out the transformed document. I believe the the XSL file is correct and is performing a valid transformation.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.*;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

/**
 *
 * @author Kirie
 */
public class getArticles extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {


            // get the xsl stored in this project 
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();                       
            InputStream xsl = (InputStream)
                                (context.getResourceAsStream("/XSLTransformerCode.xsl"));

            // We need two source objects and one result
            // get an external xml document using a url in a 
            // string format
            String topic = request.getParameter("topic");
            String urlAsString = "";
            if(topic.equals("Business"))
                urlAsString = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Business.xml";
            else if(topic.equals("Technology"))
                urlAsString = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Technology.xml";
            else if(topic.equals("World"))
                urlAsString = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml";

            Source xmlDoc =  new StreamSource(urlAsString);
            Source xslDoc =  new StreamSource(xsl);
            Result result =  new StreamResult(out);         

            // Prepare to transform 


            // The transformed document is returned to the browser.
           TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = factory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
            trans.transform(xmlDoc,result);

            out.println(result.toString());

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getArticles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getArticles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

This is the servlet that is performing the translation. You can visit the XML documents from the URL specified above. They are RSS feeds.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <h1>News Articles</h1>
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select = "rss/channel/item">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select = "title"/>
        </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XSL file I am using to transform the file. Unfortunately, I do not know where the problem is. I have tried to figure things out, but I can't seem to do that. Any input will be helpful and appreciated. I'll be online for awhile so I will be able to answer questions!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>News Articles</h1>
<ul>
<li>Obama to Seek War Power Bill From Congress, to Fight ISIS</li>
<li>Kayla Mueller&rsquo;s Parents Are Said to Receive Photos of Her Corpse From ISIS</li>
<li>Towers of Secrecy: Mexican Political Family Has Close PRI Ties, and Homes in the U.S.</li>
<li>Jordan and Emirates Carry Out Airstrikes in Syria Against Islamic State</li>
<li>Australia Holds 2 in Terrorism Case</li>
<li>Bangkok Journal: In Thailand, the Ghost Business Thrives</li>
<li>Open Source: On YouTube, Vivid Evidence of War&rsquo;s Horror in Ukraine</li>
<li>Terrorist Claims Return Sept. 11 Suit to Spotlight</li>
<li>Obama to Recall Military Personnel From Ebola Zone, Officials Say</li>
<li>Agreement on Ukraine Cease-Fire Deal Is Reported</li>
<li>Venezuela Announces Plan to Relax Currency Controls</li>
<li>India&rsquo;s Aam Aadmi Party Sweeps Elections in Delhi</li>
<li>World Briefing: New DNA Tests Ordered in Argentine Prosecutor&rsquo;s Death</li>
<li>Robert Herzstein, 74, Dies; Historian Linked a U.N. Leader to War Crimes</li>
<li>Niger Adds Its Troops to the War on Boko Haram</li>
<li>Yemeni Militant Leader Pledges to Share Power</li>
<li>Dominique Strauss-Kahn&rsquo;s Defense: He Didn&rsquo;t Know Prostitutes Were at the Orgies</li>
<li>At War Blog: For Many Veterans, &lsquo;American Sniper,&rsquo; Right or Wrong, Starts an Important Conversation</li>
<li>Battered Ukrainian City of Mariupol Braces for Worst as Rebels Close In</li>
<li>Sinosphere Blog: University President Sees Echoes of Cultural Revolution in New Campaign</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran the XSLT in a normal java application and dumped the result into a file. The above HTML code is the result that was given.

Thanks in advance!
Kirie

Comment: What's the current behaviour? You don't see any output?

Comment: Correct. There is no output when the servlet loads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct *content-type* header

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
```

Currently, the browser is trying to interpret your XML as HTML and hence renders nothing.

---

Try changing the last line from `out.println(result.toString());` to `out.flush();` I believe it's unnecessary as the `transform()` would also print to `out` through `StreamResult`. And, also change to content-type back to html.

Comment: The XSLT creates a document that is proper HTML. I uploaded (in the question) the results of when I run the XLST code against the XML from the World news RSS feed. It tried to set the content type to text/xml and it gave me this message.."This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." There is nothing shown below. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you just change the last line from `out.println(result.toString());` to `out.flush();`? I believe it's unnecessary as the `transform()` would also print to `out` through `Result`. And, also change to content-type back to html.

Comment: That's what I thought to. out.flush() doesn't change anything. I am afraid that it is not properly grabbing the two XSL file or the XML file. Do you know a way to check to make sure those resources were properly retrieved?

Comment: Construct a `StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();` and create the result as `new StreamResult(buffer);` Post transfromation log `buffer.toString()` to see the output.